# Resetting CountDownTimer to a new date when finished?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have a countdown to a certain date using the android CountDownTimer, when the timer is finished it says 'Finished' but what I would really like it to do is restart the timer but to a new date? is this possible? I've tried typing out the code I already have in the onFinish method but it doesn't seem to work and throws up a few errors.

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//Creating the TextView for the countdown
    final TextView tv_countdown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdown_text_view);

//Set the Calendar Date and Time
    Calendar start_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar end_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    end_calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    end_calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    end_calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 06);
    end_calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    end_calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    end_calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    long start_millis = start_calendar.getTimeInMillis(); //get the start time in milliseconds
    long end_millis = end_calendar.getTimeInMillis(); //get the end time in milliseconds
    long total_millis = (end_millis - start_millis); //total time in milliseconds

    //Convert the time from milliseconds to the correct time specified
    //1000 = 1 second interval
    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(total_millis, 1000) {    
@Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);

            long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);

            long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);

            long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished);

            //Set the TextVew output
            tv_countdown.setText(days + " Days" + "\n" + hours + " Hours" + "\n" + minutes + " Minutes" + "\n" + seconds + " Seconds"); }

        //Set Output when countdown finishes
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            tv_countdown.setText("Finished!");

        }
    };
    cdt.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create a new class extends `CountDownTimer` in your Activity
 and when its finished you can create new instance